# Login System in C using files

Tags: c

Hi guys I´m making a project and i need a login system, waht I currently got only checks the first user written in the file, i have several users created but i get an error will checking them (with the exception of the first user created).

This is the function to cehck the user.

```
void loginCliente(){
system("cls");

char nome[50];
char password[50];
int res;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("clientes.dat","rb");

if (fp == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("\nErro\n"); 
    exit (1); 
}

struct loginCliente lc;

getchar();
printf("\n Introduza o username: \n");
scanf("%s", nome);

printf("\n Introduza a password: \n");
scanf("%s", password);

while(fread(&lc,sizeof(lc),1,fp)){
    
    if(strcmp(lc.nome,nome) == 0){
        if(strcmp(lc.password,password) == 0){
        
            printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
            printf("\n Login efetuado com sucesso \n");
            printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
            printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para Continuar \n");
            getch();

            menuEmpresa();
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Erro \n");
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para voltar \n");
        getch();

        menuInicial();
    }
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: When using `scanf` to get a string, do *not* use the `&`.  `scanf("%s", &password);`  is wrong.  Correct is: `scanf("%s", password);`

Comment: Do you know *why* it only checks the first user in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because of the validation logic you're using; you validate the first user here `if(strcmp(lc.nome,nome) == 0)`, but if the `strcmp()` return a value diferent from 0, fallowing your logic, you'll display an error message and, than, execute the function `menuInicial()`; to solve this issue I recomend you to add a flag to your loop and use it to end the loop -so, after you find the user, you don't need to keep searching for it on the bin file- and to call this "error method".

```
int flag=0;
while(fread(&lc,sizeof(lc),1,fp)&&!flag){
    if(!strcmp(lc.nome,nome)&&!strcmp(lc.password,password)){            
        flag=1;
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Login efetuado com sucesso \n");
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para Continuar \n");
        getch();
        menuEmpresa();
    }
}
if(!flag){
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n Erro \n");
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para voltar \n");
    getch();
    menuInicial();
}
```

I'd also recomend to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`; I hope it's helpfull

Comment: Hey L.Bravo ichanged the code a bit and now it´s working thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs some help with this, the code that worked for me is the following:

```
void loginCliente(){
system("cls");

char nome[50];
char password[50];
int res;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("clientes.dat","rb");

if (fp == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("\nErro\n"); 
    exit (1); 
}

struct loginCliente lc;

getchar();
printf("\n Introduza o username: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", nome);

printf("\n Introduza a password: \n");
scanf("%s", password);

int flag=0;
while(fread(&lc,sizeof(lc),1,fp)){
    if(!strcmp(lc.nome,nome)&&!strcmp(lc.password,password)){            
        flag=1;
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Login efetuado com sucesso \n");
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para Continuar \n");
        getch();
        menuEmpresa();
    }
}
if(!flag){
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n Erro \n");
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para voltar \n");
    getch();
    menuInicial();
}

    fclose(fp);
}
```